# What are the foundational papers of neural networks and how can I find them?

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks, research

I am researching neural networks and would like to read some of the first papers that established and/or popularized neural networks. Neural networks crosses over between many fields, so I am looking for one with more of a mathematical perspective, in particular with a precise definition for the network. I have tried googling "foundational papers of neural networks" and and also tried some searches on the arxiv. How would you go about finding a paper like this? Do you know of any foundational papers on neural networks?

Thanks.

Comment: This page about the history of neural networks seems helpful: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/neural-networks/History/history1.html This history of neural network architectures also might be helpful: https://www.topbots.com/a-brief-history-of-neural-network-architectures/#:~:text=LeNet5%20was%20invented%20in%201994,iterations%20since%20the%20year%201988!